# creating and appending variables inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically make an unordered list using javascript, where I just have to list the number of items that I want and it will display it in the list.

example input prompt "how many list items would you like?" if we input 2 and enter
it should return

```
  <ul>
    
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    
    </ul>
```

I've simplified the HTML and javascript but i tried wrap the append and create variables in a for loop and nothing happened.
heres the code html :

```js
    const numberofitemsel = document.getElementById('num-of-navitems');
        const numberofitems = parseInt(numberofitemsel.value);
    
        const body = document.body;
    
    
        const savebtn = document.getElementById('save');
       savebtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        let ul =document.createElement("ul");
    // append to body 
    
    
    
       body.append(ul);
       // create list items 
       
       for(var i=0;i<=numberofitems;i++){
        let li=document.createElement("li");
        li.innerText="hi";
 
 
 
 
 
    // append to ul
    ul.appendChild(li);
   }
});
```

```html
   

 <main>
      <h4>how many list items do you want?</h4>
      <input type="number" id="num-of-navitems">
      <button type="button" id="save">save</button>
    </main>
```

so the output I want is the if I input 3 into my input box I want three list items:

```
<ul>

<li>hi</li>
<li>hi</li>
<li>hi</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: There's no for loop in your code

Comment: What is the `body` variable?

Comment: @user17517503 `const body = document.body;`

Comment: In the `for` loop, the `numberofitems` is a `HTMLElementObject`, not a number. You should use `Number(numberofitems.value)`, because the value returns a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `for` loop in the `savebtn.eventListener`:

```
for(let i=0;i<Math.floor(Number(numberofitemsel.value));i++) {
 let li = document.createElement("li");
 li.innerText = "hi";
 // append to ul
 ul.appendChild(li);
  }
```

The other parts of your code are OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate `numberofitemsel.value` **after** the user clicks the button, not before.

```js
const numberOfItemsEl = document.getElementById('num-of-navitems');
const body = document.body;
const savebtn = document.getElementById('save');
savebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const numberOfItems = parseInt(numberOfItemsEl.value);
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  body.append(ul);
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = "hi";
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

```html
<main>
  <h4>how many list items do you want?</h4>
  <input type="number" id="num-of-navitems">
  <button type="button" id="save">save</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const main = document.querySelector("#main");
const mainUl = document.querySelector("#mainUl");
const inputText = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const taskBtn = document.querySelector("#addTask");

function addTask(times) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "hi";
    mainUl.appendChild(li);
  }
}
taskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inputText.value == "") {
    alert("please enter number!!");
  } else {
    addTask(inputText.value);
    inputText.value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter Number" />
  <button id="addTask">Add List</button><br />
  <ul id="mainUl"></ul>
</div>
```